# Scipy banded eigensolver much slower than standard eigensolver

Tags: numpy, performance, scipy, linear-algebra, eigenvalue

I'm observing a strange behaviour concerning the `scipy.linalg.eig_banded` eigensolver.

I am generating banded matrices of size N=p*f that have a specific structure. The matrices are symmetric tri-block-diagonal with p blocks of size fxf on the main diagonal and p-1 identity matrices of size f*f on the off diagonals.

Example with p=3 and f=3:

```
 [2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 1 0 0 0 0]
 [2 2 2 0 0 1 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 3 3 3 1 0 0]
 [0 1 0 3 3 3 0 1 0]
 [0 0 1 3 3 3 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0 0 4 4 4]
 [0 0 0 0 1 0 4 4 4]
 [0 0 0 0 0 1 4 4 4]
```

Usually these matrices are of size p = 100, f=30, N=p*f=3000 but can easily grow much larger.

Given the structure of these matrices I was hoping that the banded eigensolver in scipy was going to be much faster than the dense eigensolver, however it seems like this is not the case.

I am benchmarking the solvers with the following code:

```py
# Set dimension of problem
f = 50
p = 80
a = 1

print(f"p={p}, f={f}, size={f*p, f*p}")

print(f"Matrix containing random numbers in {(-a, a)}")
A = generate_matrix(p, f, -a, a)

# Benchmark standard eigensolver
start = time()
D, Q = linalg.eigh(A)
end = time()

# Test correctness
D = np.diag(D)
print(f"Time for dense solver {end - start}")
print(f"||AQ - QD|| = {np.linalg.norm(A@Q - Q@D)}")


# Convert A to banded format
A_banded = banded_format(A, upper = f)

# Benchmark banded eigensolver
start = time()
D, Q = linalg.eig_banded(A_banded)
end = time()

# Test correctness
D = np.diag(D)
print(f"Time for banded solver {end - start}")
print(f"||AQ - QD|| = {np.linalg.norm(A@Q - Q@D)}")
```

The results I get indicate that the banded eigensolver is much slower than the dense one:

```
p=80, f=50, size=(4000, 4000)
Matrix containing random numbers in (-1, 1)

Time for dense solver 13.475645780563354
||AQ - QD|| = 3.1334336527852233e-12

Time for banded solver 24.427151203155518
||AQ - QD|| = 1.589349711533356e-11
```

I have already tried storing the matrix in lower diagonal format and passing the `overwrite_a_band=True` option, but the performance remains the same.

Numpy configuration:

```
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
```

Scipy configuration:

```
lapack_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_lapack_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
lapack_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
blas_mkl_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
blis_info:
  NOT AVAILABLE
openblas_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
blas_opt_info:
    libraries = ['openblas', 'openblas']
    library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
    language = c
    define_macros = [('HAVE_CBLAS', None)]
    runtime_library_dirs = ['/cluster/apps/gcc-8.2.0/openblas-0.2.20-5gatj7a35vypgjekzf3ibbtz54tlbk3m/lib']
```

I also tried running the same benchmark on a different cluster using MKL as a backend instead of OpenBLAS and I observed very similar results. Also setting the number of threads with `OMP_NUM_THREADS` and/or `MKL_NUM_THREADS` has a very small effect on performance.

Does anyone have any ideas on why this is happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did some digging into the source code of SciPy and the Intel MKL documentation and I have figured out why this is happening.

The scipy `eig_banded` solver delegates the problem to the LAPACK `dsbevd` routine which computes all eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix in banded format using a variation of the Cuppen divide and conquer algorithm. This offers an advantage in terms of memory usage because of the banded storage format, but the actual algorithm scales in O(n^3) flops after tridiagonalization with respect to matrix size.

On the other hand, the scipy dense eigensolver delegates the problem to the `dsyev` routine which for real symmetric matrices calls the `dsyevr` routine which computes the eigenvalues and eigenvectors using the MRRR algorithm in O(n^2) flops after tridiagonalization.

I am still unsure why there is no MRRR implementation for banded matrix format in MKL.